# The authenticity of host can't be established but that host is in known_hosts file

Tags: ssh, hosts, fingerprint

In order to skip initial SSH negotiation, I have added the public key of the server I am going to connect to inside my `known_hosts` file, following [these](https://superuser.com/a/971768) suggestions.
However, when trying to connect to server, it seems to be not recognized:

```
user@hostname:~$ ssh -p SERVER_PORT other@SERVER_IP
The authenticity of host '[SERVER_IP]:SERVER_PORT ([SERVER_IP]:SERVER_PORT)' can't be established. 
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:prZ6ezy5sWx+LUEXw5MQzJcbQci6Ji97vnS5Q0izSH0. 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How could I solve it?

**Update:**

Launching `ssh` with `-vvv`, I can see the following line:

```
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:prZ6ezy5sWx+LUEXw5MQzJcbQci6Ji97vnS5Q0izSH0
```

And in `known_hosts` I have added:

```
SERVER_IP_HASH ssh-rsa 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 COMMENT
```

Comment: You should show us the line from known_hosts since it's just a public key. Also have a look at (and show relevant parts from) what happens when you run ssh verbosely: `ssh -vvv`. In particular, the host key shows up there, so it should be possible to determine where things aren't matching up right.

Comment: @cryptarch, I have modified the question adding more information in clear. Are the some other portions of the `-vvv` output that could be useful for this question?

Comment: If you say "yes" to the prompt the public key will be added to the known_hosts file correctly for you, and thereafter you won't be prompted again. I don't understand what it is that you think you're saving

Comment: So, when I put your public key into a file and run `ssh-keygen -l -f <filename>` on it, I see the hash is different to what is being provided to your client: `SHA256:0Aita5WqRruDUIYWD62kDb1CO1Arf7YnJCpNHzi4ci4`. In fact, even the key types are different, the host is giving you ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 and your public key is RSA.

Comment: And @roaima is correct, just let the client ask you if the new key is correct. If you're not sure, you can just say no. And if you need a way to formally verify that the host is really the host you're thinking of, you should look into ssh certificates.

Answer (score 1):

A server can have multiple host keys.  In your case, you've specified an RSA host key, but the server is presenting you with an ECDSA host key.  Because these are not the same host key, you've been prompted.

Normally, OpenSSH prefers host key algorithms for which it already has keys over ones which it does not, so this should work out of the box.  However, if you've configured the `HostKeyAlgorithms` option explicitly, OpenSSH will honor it and prefer the algorithms you've specified.  You can look in your `~/.ssh/config` file and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` files to see if that's the case, and if so, add an entry to your `~/.ssh/config` file like this:

```
# Update with the real IP address.
Host 192.0.2.1
  HostKeyAlgorithms rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
```

Note that this enables the use of SHA-1 signatures (`ssh-rsa`), which you should avoid if possible.  If you know the server supports SHA-2 signatures, you can remove it.

It could also be the case that the entry you've explicitly added is not correct.  Some systems, such as Debian, use hashed entries, while others do not.  You'll have to check the same configuration files for `HashKnownHosts` and adjust the entry accordingly.  You can use `ssh-keygen -F 192.0.2.1 -l` (replacing the IP address) to see if there's a match for the entry.